# Inserting array into Mongo collections

Tags: php, mongodb

Am trying to insert $json into MongoDB. My idea is, to foreach/looping the array to get only 'statuses'.

$json is passed from another function. Looks like this :

```
{
  "statuses": [
    {
      "created_at": "Fri Apr 22",
      "id": 123,
      "text": "Sample text 1",
    },
    {
      "created_at": "Fri Apr 22",
      "id": 321,
      "text": "Sample text 1",
    }
  ],
  "search_metadata": {
    "count": 2,
    "since_id": 0,
    "since_id_str": "0"
  }
}
```

Code

```
<?php 

$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->selectDB("newDB");
$collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'newStatus');

// looping through $json
foreach ($json as $document){
  // another looping to get 'statuses'
  foreach($document['statuses'] as $status) {
    // store into MongoDB
    $collection->insert(json_decode($status));
  }
}

?>
```

Revised : above code works! Adding in `$collection->insert(json_decode($document));`

However, it store the whole chunk of array. I just want the 'statuses'.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: KInd of guessing that `$json` here actually contains a "string". You need to `json_decode` that into a PHP data structure first.

Comment: @NeilLunn actually I've tried that, but it will change to PHP array. Whereas from example I got, MongoDB accept string just fine.

Comment: They are **not** strings. The examples on the site a JavaScript objects because the `mongo` "shell" uses "JavaScript". All data structures need to be **native** to the language you are actually working in. So yeah! It's meant to be a PHP array.